# $\frac{d}{dt} \int_t^\infty f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus

[image]
[image]

How do we ge the above derivative? Specifically, I am not sure what the derivatives of the last two terms are, i.e., $\frac{d}{dt} \int_t^\infty xf(x)dx$ and $\frac{d}{dt} \int_t^\infty f(x)dx$. Why do we have the term $k[1-F(t)]$?

Comment: Unfortunately, the search option at MSE can't read pictures yet, so can I request you to typeset this question so that other users with the same question can find this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under mild regularity assumptions you can just use the fundamental theorem of calculus and say that

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_t^{+\infty} x f(x) dx = - t f(t), \quad \frac{d}{dt} \int_t^{+\infty}  f(x) dx = -  f(t)
$$

We are assuming that $xf(x)$ and $f(x)$ are integrable in every interval $[t, b]$ and that $\displaystyle \lim_{b \to +\infty}\int_t^b x f(x) dx$, $\displaystyle \lim_{b \to +\infty}\int_t^b f(x) dx$ exist.

Comment: Could you also explain why we have $k[1-F(t)]$?

Comment: $$\int_t^{+\infty} f(x) dx = 1- \int_{-\infty}^t f(x) dx = 1- F(t)$$

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was confused about.

Comment: Please note that we are not computing primitives... The result is that 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^t w(x) dx = w(t)
$$

In this case I just skipped converting the improper integral into a limit, but the result is the same.

Comment: Actually you can get the same results for measurable functions. You don't really need those mild conditions.

Comment: @MarineGalantin Sure, the result is more general then I stated.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_t^\infty f(x)dx=-f(t)$$

Comment: I was able to get this. Could you also explain why we have $k[1-F(t)]$?

Comment: not very informative. This is the whole point of the question. I ve set -1.